# PHP can't connect, but SqlPlus can

Tags: php, oracle, sqlplus

Here is an issue that is boggling my cells right now.

There is an oracle server that I want to connect to. I can easily connect to it using the sqlplus command line.

When I try to connect to the oracle database with PHP though, it fails. Here is the catch, we have the same setup in another datacenter; a PHP machine is trying to connect to an oracle database. I've run the exact same code, configured php identically on both PHP machines.

PHP1 can connect to Oracle1 with both sqlplus and through php.

PHP2 connects to Oracle2 with sqlplus but NOT with PHP.

There are firewalls and some port blocking going on. My current explanation is that the port php2 is using to connect to oracle2 is not the default 1521 and it is being blocked.

The ora error I get is :

ORA-06413 : Connection not open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the port isn't 1521 - can you see the connection details SQL*Plus is using, e.g. in your `tnsnames.ora` if you're using an alias? It seems unlikely that it's a network or firewall issue if one client can connect and another can't. I'm assuming both connections are being attempted from the same client machine, is that true?

Comment: If you've configured php identically on both machines, why would one of them connect using a different port? If it did, I'd say you haven't configured them identically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the TNS connect descriptor can't be parsed for one reason or another. It's usually a problem with a system call made by Oracle when it's attempting to build connection information.

Are there any brackets in your program name, username, or machine name?

Are you running a 32-bit Oracle client on a 64-bit Windows OS by any chance?

Try using the tnsping utility from the command line. What does that tell you?

Comment: PHP was in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP. All I had to do was put it in a path with no parentheses. ( C:\PHP )

Answer (score 0):

From the info provided, my best guess (narrowing it to programming causes) is that either the database name, username or password sent from the problem machine contains an escape sequence (`$`, `\t`, `\a`, `\r`, etc.) that, when typed in your PHP script as a string literal, becomes altered.

Comment: I had thought that too originally but the connection strings on both PHP2 and PHP1 are identically written. Meaning that they are both written in the following format '10.10.10.10:1521/databaseName'

Comment: Well, if there are no escape sequences and the code is otherwise identical, it may be a networking/config issue. This may have to be migrated over to serverfault.

Comment: Thanks webbiedave. Maybe a moderator will do that for me.