# Oracle 11 instant client connect to remote Oracle 8i server: ORA-12514 error

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I encountered a problem that I have spent hours fixing that. Here is the problem:

I am trying to connect to a remote Oracle 8i server using ***Oracle 11 instant client***: here is my connection string in PHP:

> $conn = oci_connect('db_user', 'db_pass', "db_ip/db_service");

db_ip is the ip of the server, such as "12.34.56.78".
db_service is the service of server, such as "test".

The error shown is

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I could use the same client to connect to another Oracle 10g server. The php code is same, only change the db_user or db_pass or db_ip. db_service is not provided.

I don't use tnsnames.ora for either oracle 10g server or oracle 8i server.  I just use the simple IP of server. Does this matter?

```
Server using: Windows Server 2008 R2
PHP: php 5.2.17
Oracle Instant Client: 11_2
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

**Updated**
Php can also work now. My php folder is under Programfiles (x86), the parenthesis is not allowed. So I moved the whole folder to C:\php, and configure the IIS to change php version. Reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215983/php-cant-connect-but-sqlplus-can

**Updated**
Thanks so much for Justin's help. It works!!! I just changed the sid to scblive instead of SCBLIVE. Their database name is scblive. I am still using 10.2.0.1, using sqlplus, I can connect to both oracle 10g and oracle 8i. Thanks soooo much!!

This is the tns names that works for oracle 8i:

> scblive =
>    (DESCRIPTION =
>      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [oracle 8i ip])(PORT = 1521))
>      (CONNECT_DATA =
>        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>        (SID = scblive)
>      )
>    )

Another problem found, in php code,  it shows the same error for either oracle 10g or oracle 8i.

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I just used following connection string:

> $conn = oci_connect('user_name', 'pass', 'scblive');

for oracle 10g, if I used same connection string as before, the error still shows:

> $conn = oci_connect('user_name', 'pass', [oracle 10g ip]);

Any ideas?

**Earilier Update**:
Thanks for @Justin's help. have tried 10.2.0.5, 10.2.0.4 or 10.1.0.0, none of them could  work. I saw the the matrix. it seems instant client 8.1.7 or instant client 9.0.1 could work for both oracle 10g and oracle 8i. Does anyone have a link for those files? Oracle could only provide 10.1.0.5 and later.

Comment: Note that 10.2.0.5 was the first version of the Oracle client that worked on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server (and that support had to be backported-- the original intention was not to support 10.2 clients on Windows 2008 R2).  If you want an earlier version of the Oracle client, you would need to install a different version of Windows on the server.  You could then file a support request with Oracle to get the older versions of the software.  The Instant Client product is also relatively new-- if you want an 8.1.7 or 9.0.1 client, it would need to be the full client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  The 11.2 client is not certified to connect with any version of Oracle 8i.  You would need to have at least an Oracle 9.2.0.4 database.  If you want to connect with and 8.1.7 database, you would need an Oracle 10.2 or earlier client.  The initial versions of the 10.2 client were not compatible with a Windows Server 2008 R2 system but it should be possible to install the 10.2.0.5 client patchset.  If you want to connect to an Oracle database that is earlier than 8.1.7, you would need an earlier version of the Oracle client which would probably require installing an earlier version of Windows.

If you have Metalink access, Metalink 207303.1 is the [Client/ Server Interoperability Matrix](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=207303.1).

If you really have the 10.2.0.5 full client installed, your TNS alias needs to use a SID.  Service names didn't exist back in 8.1.7.  You probably want to copy a TNS alias from a machine that is able to connect to the 8.1.7 database.  My guess is that you want

```
SCBLIVE = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [ORACLE 8i IP])(PORT = 1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = SCBLIVE)) 
  )
```

If that doesn't work, at a command line, type `tnsping scblive` and copy and paste the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just installed instant client 10.2.0.5 win32 (I was using 11.2 32bit), however, it still cannot work. The oci module cannot be loaded "The specified module could not be found", so I cannot even connect oracle 10g using this client. I am asking the server people to let them check the oracle version to see if it is 8.1.7 or earlier.

Comment: @user1631658 - Is your Windows 2008 R2 server not 64-bit?  It would seem likely that you would want the 64-bit client.  I assume that the 10.2.0.5 Instant Client is supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.  You may, though, want to test the full client install.

Comment: Just tested. 64bit 10.2.0.5 cannot work either. same problem "MSVCR71.DLL is missing from your computer"

Comment: could use sqlplus by moving MSVCR71.dll to that folder, and oci module could be loaded now. but still get "ORA-12514 error" for oracle 8i server, also get "ORA-12514 error"  for oracle 10g server now. Any ideas?

Comment: for full client, do I have to install Oracle 8.1.7 or 9.01. ?

Comment: I have checked oracle 8i server version:  8.1.7.0.0.  Instant client 10.2.0.5 cannot work with that?

Comment: @user1631658 - I would expect that the 10.2.0.5 Instant Client would work with an 8.1.7.0.0 database and that the 10.2.0.5 Instant Client would be supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.  But you are on the very edge of both-- 10.2 is the latest version of the client that was ever supported to connect to 8.1.7.0 and 10.2.0.5 is the very first version of the client that was supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.  Plus, you're using the Instant Client rather than the full client which further complicates things.  I would tend to try the full 10.2.0.5 client to see if that works.

Comment: We installed Oracle full client 8.1.7, the oci module cannot be loadded. I tried using sqlplus to connect to the remote oracle server, still failed. Can we use ODBC to connect instead of oci?

Comment: @user1631658 - The 10.2.0.5 client was the first version of the client that was supported on Windows Server 2008 R2. Unless you are moving to a different operating system on the server, I would not expect an earlier version of the full client to install successfully or to work correctly. And no later version of the client will connect to an 8.1.7.0 database. 10.2.0.5 is the only version of the client that I would expect to work with the combination of client operating system and server version that you are trying to use (one of the problems with mixing ancient and modern versions of software).

Comment: thanx a lot.  I changed my tnsname.ora according to that. still shows "TNS-12541: TNS: no listerner". the content is as follows: Attempting to contact (Description = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [IP])(PORT =1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER=DEDICATED) (SID = SCBLIVE))) TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: Hi Justin, It works!!! I changed the sid to scblive instead of SCBLIVE. Their database name is scblive. I am still using 10.2.0.1, using sqlplus, I can connect to both oracle 10g and oracle 8i. Thanks soooo much!!

Comment: Here is another problem. in php, it cannot work for either oracle 10g or oracle 8i. I am using sth as oci_connect('username', 'pass', 'scblive'), it shows: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Answer (score 0):

I copy my previous Oracle 9/8 client's ora.... folder and all relevant dll to a specific folder and put these two folders into path variable. At a time, I succeed to connecting with Oracle 8.1.7 using oci in php.